# horizontal listview in info window google map v2

Tags: android, listview, google-maps-api-2

I creating a application base on **google map api v2**

I want to put a `horizontal list view` contain `image` , which get from sd card, into info window 
 there is my c`ustomwindow adapter class`

```
class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View mWindow;
    private final View mContents;
    LinearLayout myGallery;

    CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        mWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                null);
        mContents = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.custom_info_contents_with_listview, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

        render(marker, mWindow);
        return mWindow;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        render(marker, mContents);
        return mContents;
    }

    private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        int badge = 0;

        myGallery = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);

        // get file from sd card
        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/DCIM/Camera";

        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

        File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();

        if (marker.equals(listMarkers.get(0))) {
            for (File file : files) {
                       myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }

        String title = marker.getTitle();
        TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        if (title != null) {

            SpannableString titleText = new SpannableString(title);
            titleText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0,
                    titleText.length(), 0);
            titleUi.setText(titleText);
        } else {
            titleUi.setText("");
        }

        String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        if (snippet != null && snippet.length() > 12) {
            SpannableString snippetText = new SpannableString(snippet);
            snippetText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.MAGENTA), 0,
                    10, 0);
            snippetText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 12,
                    snippet.length(), 0);
            snippetUi.setText(snippetText);
        } else {
            snippetUi.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

**when i run the code , locat show Null pointer exeption at**

```
 for (File file : files) {
                            myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

**xml code**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mygallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

thank in advance for any help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you have a `NullPointerException` but even if you will put all your images into this `InfoWindow` layout you will not be able to scroll it as the `InfoWindow` is not a real view. It's just a rendered `SurfaceView`. So you can't apply `onTouch` or `onClick` events on it.

From `Google Docs`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`.
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

Comment: Thank you very much . I will find another way .

Comment: You welcome : ) You should upvote/accept the answer if it was helpful to you.